# What system logs might tell me if a server lost its internet connection?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, rhel, syslog

I have a server:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I think its network connection cutout at one point (its back now). I haven't been able to find anything in /var/log/messages- maybe I just don't know what to look for?

Essesntially I'm looking for two things: If there was a problem with the nic, If the server lost its internet connection.

The second one is obviously harder to figure out (maybe impossible?). Obviously I should have some external monitoring solution, but from an educational perspective where would you look (locally on the host) to solve this mystery?

Comment: unless application, such as mail use internet, and if your local network was OK, I doubt there could be log somewhere to see that.

Comment: bummer, just curious if there was any sneaky forensics nix nerds know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ring kernel buffer (`dmesg`) - you should see information for network connectivity events.

Comment: Cool theres some neat stuff in there. I see mostly systemd stuff?

Comment: `dmesg` displays information about hardware (connect/disconnect devices, drivers etc)

Answer (score 2):

Your kernel logs (the most recent viewable by `dmesg`, older by `journalctl -k` or wherever configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`) will probably contain messages if a NIC loses its link. And of course you can easily find what those messages look like by unplugging the cable. Example:

```
Jan 13 11:16:33 Zia kernel: r8169 0000:07:01.0 lan: link down
```

Loss of Internet connectivity is harder, and typically you'd set something up to detect this (either external monitoring, or monitoring of outside machines from your machine). It's also not really a binary state—you can have partial Internet connectivity (can reach some hosts, but not all). You can look for clues, though:

- messages from NTP in the journal/logs (e.g., about losing peers), or check the NTP peer stats (if enabled).
- messages in journal/logs about failed network connections (e.g., if you had fetchmail running routinely, it'd complain it couldn't connect to your POP3 server)
- VPN connections going down (I get plenty of OpenVPN logs when the Internet connection goes down).
- sudden 0 load on web (etc.) servers. Many servers log all requests received to some server-specific log.
- similarly, if you log system load (load average, run queue, etc.), quick drop to 0 is a clue.
- lack of noise in firewall logs (at least, if you log blocked packets)
- sudden lack of random worm attacks (I get plenty of failed authentication messages from various services I'm running, and not getting any for hours would be a good clue there was no Internet connectivity)
- traffic levels, if you're monitoring (e.g., using Cacti, MRTG, collectd, etc.). If you're not, your ISP probably is—maybe they'd be willing to share?
- if you have other machines that talk to this machine, check those machine's logs. Might have failure messages
- if you offer services to other people, they might have logs.
- if you have a support desk, they probably know (from all the calls they got).

Basically, you're doing detective work: you need to look for clues. Without monitoring, there isn't going to be an *teh Interwebs is down* log message.

Comment: OTOH Mac OS X spams the `system.log` with `Internet connection appears to be offline` messages when it is so.