# Where is the network data is stored on linux system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, android, proc

is there a way I can find information about my wifi connections? Which networks I was connected to and when? I had tried to look for this information under proc/net but found nothing.
(To be more specific I want to find this information on my android device.)

Comment: Network-Manager package internals. I don't know precisely, where, but I could find it.

Comment: Please note : An [unanswerd old question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490080/how-to-read-information-about-wifi-connection-from-proc-net) is flagged as duplicate of this.

Answer (score 3):

History of connections isn't stored explicitly on Linux, and you have to discern between hardware information and networking information. One example of hardware-specific information would be [`dmesg`, which may show you information about specific hardware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337173/85039), i.e. whether a link is up or down, however names of specific WiFi access points aren't logged.

It's worth noting also that setup depends on what system your Linux distribution is using. Many Debian-based systems, such as Ubuntu and Deepin, use Network Manager. As such all wireless connections which have been configured have appropriate file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folders. Each file for each connection, if we're talking about WiFi connection, would have the password and BSSID of the access point. File name is the ESSID, although for networks which may have same ESSID shared accross multiple BSSID access points (for instance, my university has same WiFi access point name in different buildings with different routers) - those would have a numeric suffix in addition to the access point name. Note that you have to have root privilege to see all of that information, although from desktop applets you can also view that.  I can't comment on other network management utilities as I've never used those.

It is however possible to implement such logging, since at least Network Manager sends information about the connections via DBus interprocess communication subsystems, so it can be scripted via `dbus-monitor` utility for instance.

Another thing that could be considered in implementing such logging is DHCP leases. Systems that use `systemd` should provide information about IP address leases from which gateway in `journalctl` output. See [related post](https://superuser.com/a/945120/418028) for reference.

If you're asking about Android specifically, note that android.stackexchange.com should be more appropriate place to ask, however I suspect also that on Android there's similar logging practices - i.e., it's not recorded when device has connected to an access point but only which one. Again, there's specific location for such information. According to [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/21299/86444):

> On CyanogenMod devices, and possibly other AOSP ROMs, you should be able to grab it from the /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Accessing any system level information , including the above referenced file, on Android requires root.

Answer (score 1):

> Which networks I was connected to?

The `iw` command allow you to get on which network you are already connected:

```
iw dev <Interface> link
```

e.g.:

```
iw dev wlan0 link | grep SSID
```

Or using the depricated command `iwgetid`.

> When?

By checking the `wpa_supplicant` events from `syslog` :

```
# cat /var/log/syslog | grep wpa_supplicant
```

e,g : using termux terminal on an android with root access:

```
$ tsu
# logcat | grep -i wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what if I don't have root access on the device? Is it still possible to get this information?

Comment: @Keselme Using `dmesg` posted on @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's answer. `dmesg -T | grep -i wlan0` , use `ip a` command to get the exact interface name.

Comment: If `wlan0` doesn't work for you, use `ip addr` to find out the names of the interfaces you have. Operating systems using systemd use different naming scheme. See also https://askubuntu.com/a/704364/295286